# Store value of a key in a returned object from mongo in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Ok let me just say I am a new to meteor and am racking my brain here.  I have a collection declared of a customer.  It has the usual customer fields, address city postal etc etc.

I have the following call on this collection to return one record.

```
var customerRecord = customersColl.find({customerName: suggestion.value}).fetch();
```

This successfully returns one object with my customer record in it.  Now what I need to do is assign those values such as address, city postal etc to variables.  This is where I am failing.  Every which way I have tried I get errors or undefined.  How do I get the following to work:

```
var customerAddress = customerRecord.customerAddress.value;
```

This is the scheme I am using for this object.

```
customersColl.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    customerName:{
    type: String,
    label: "Customer:"
    },
    customerSuite: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Suite:"
    },
    customerAddress: {
        type: String,
        label: "Address:"
    },
    customerCity: {
        type: String,
        label: "City:"
    },
    customerState: {
        type: String,
        label: "State/Prov:"
    },
    customerZip: {
        type: String,
        label: "Zip/Postal"
    },
    customerPhone1: {
        type: String,
        label: "Phone 1:"
    },
    customerPhone2: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Phone 2:"
    },
    customerFax: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Fax:"
    },
    customerFactorInvoices: {
        type: Boolean,
        optional: true,
        label: "Factor Invoicing to Payment Company"
    },
    factoringName: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Company:"
    },
    factoringSuite: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Suite:"
    },
    factoringAddress: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Address:"
    },
    factoringCity: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "City:"
    },  
    factoringState: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "State/Prov:"
    },      
    factoringZip: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Zip/Postal:"
    },      
    factoringPhone1: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Phone 1:"
    },      
    factoringPhone2: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Phone 2:"
    },      
    factoringFax: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Fax:"
    },      
    factoringEmail: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
        optional: true,
        label: "Email:"
    },      
    customerOriginalInvoices: {
        type: Boolean,
        optional: true,
        label: "Require Original Invoices Mailed"
    },      
    customerAccountHold: {
        type: Boolean,
        optional: true,
        label: "Account on Hold"
    },      
    createdDate: {
        type: Date
    },      
    createdUser: {
        type: String,
    },  
    emailRoles1: {
        type: Array,
          label: "Email Roles",
          optional: true,
          autoform: {
             options: [
                {
                   label: "On Order Create",
                   value: "onOrderCreate"
                },
                {
                   label: "On PU Del",
                   value: "onPuDel"
                },
                {
                   label: "Invoicing",
                   value: "invoicing"
                },
                {
                   label: "Accounts Payable",
                   value: "accountsPayable"
                }
             ]
          }
      },
       "emailRoles1.$": {
          type: String,
          label: "Email Roles",
          optional: true
       },
    emailRoles2: {
        type: Array,
          label: "Email Roles",
          optional: true,
          autoform: {
             options: [
                {
                   label: "On Order Create",
                   value: "onOrderCreate"
                },
                {
                   label: "On PU Del",
                   value: "onPuDel"
                },
                {
                   label: "Invoicing",
                   value: "invoicing"
                },
                {
                   label: "Accounts Payable",
                   value: "accountsPayable"
                }
             ]
          }
      },
       "emailRoles2.$": {
          type: String,
          label: "Email Roles",
          optional: true
       },
    emailRoles3: {
        type: Array,
          label: "Email Roles",
          optional: true,
          autoform: {
             options: [
                {
                   label: "On Order Create",
                   value: "onOrderCreate"
                },
                {
                   label: "On PU Del",
                   value: "onPuDel"
                },
                {
                   label: "Invoicing",
                   value: "invoicing"
                },
                {
                   label: "Accounts Payable",
                   value: "accountsPayable"
                }
             ]
          }
      },
       "emailRoles3.$": {
          type: String,
          label: "Email Roles",
          optional: true
       },
    emailRoles4: {
        type: Array,
          label: "Email Roles",
          optional: true,
          autoform: {
             options: [
                {
                   label: "On Order Create",
                   value: "onOrderCreate"
                },
                {
                   label: "On PU Del",
                   value: "onPuDel"
                },
                {
                   label: "Invoicing",
                   value: "invoicing"
                },
                {
                   label: "Accounts Payable",
                   value: "accountsPayable"
                }
             ]
          }
      },
       "emailRoles4.$": {
          type: String,
          label: "Email Roles",
          optional: true
       },
    customerEmail1: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
        optional: true,
        label: "Email 1:"
    },
    customerEmail2: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
        optional: true,
        label: "Email 2:"
    },
    customerEmail3: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
        optional: true,
        label: "Email 3:"
    },
    customerEmail4: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
        optional: true,
        label: "Email 4:"
    },      
}));
```

This doesn't work but then neither did anything I tried.  Any help here to get this would be greatly appreciated.

**CORRECTED CODE**

Here is the correct code that now works with the findOne.  Thank you guys for your help.

```
        var customerRecord =  customersColl.findOne({customerName: suggestion.value});
        console.log(customerRecord.customerAddress);
```

Comment: `find` with `fetch` will return an array of results, not a single document. Try using `findOne`

Comment: That is fine I can change that and during this whole process I had it that way once. But the underline question still remains. How do I assign the values from the returned object into variables.

Comment: What you are doing _seems_ fine, but I can't say for certain without knowing the schema. What does `console.log(customerRecord)` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fetch](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) returns an array of documents. You seem to be expecting to retrieve a single document, so you should use [findOne](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone) instead:

```
var customerRecord = customersColl.findOne({customerName: suggestion.value});
```

Comment: Please see comment above